# change url using htaccess, while two variables in url

Tags: .htaccess

There are two variables in my url.
this is my home url --> **subdomain.example.com/subdirectory/abc.php**

if available the variables, url like this --> **subdomain.example.com/subdirectory/abc.php?m=p&n=q**
the **abc.php** page generate different content by getting these variables.

I use htaccess for that and it works fine.
I need to change url like this --> **subdomain.example.com/subdirectory/p/q**

The problem is site has some pages separated pages like contact.php, privacy.php

For that pages, i need to change that urls like 
**subdomain.example.com/subdirectory/contact**
**subdomain.example.com/subdirectory/privacy**

When i entered url **subdomain.example.com/subdirectory/contact**, 
abc.php is getting the first variable(m) = contact.

I need to stop that and change the url using htaccess.
please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file **in your `/subdirectory/`**:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

# Append the .php extension
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# pass parameters to abc.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ abc.php?m=$1&n=$2 [L,QSA]
```